# Reload Parent Window without POST

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am trying to reload a parent window (same domain) with javascript from within an iframe.

```
window.parent.location.href = window.parent.location.href;
```

does not work here for some reason (no javascript errors).

I don't believe it is a problem with same origin policy, as the following works:

```
window.parent.location.reload();
```

The problem with this option is if the last request was a POST, it gets reloaded as POST.

Any ideas why the first option wouldn't work?  Otherwise, is there another method that will reload the page without resubmitting any form data (e.g. perform a fresh GET request to the parent page URL)?

I have also tried:

```
top.frames.location.href = top.frames.location.href;
window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href
```

and various other iterations.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "reload the page without resubmitting any form data"?  You want the server to re-generate the page, but without the inputs it normally uses to do so?  Or do you want the page to be reloaded from the browser's cache?

Comment: If you use location.reload(), and the last request was POST, the POST is repeated.  I want to perform a fresh GET request to the same url.

Comment: Are there any parameters you want to pass to the GET request?

Comment: Just the existing ones on the original URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this code:

```
window.location.href = window.location.href;
```

in an ordinary page (no frames) and it had no effect either.  The browser must detect that it is the same URL being displayed and conclude that no action needs to be taken.

What you can do is add a dummy GET parameter and change it to force the browser to reload.  The first load might look like this (with POST data included, not shown here of course):

```
http://www.example.com/page.html?a=1&b=2&dummy=32843493294348
```

Then to reload:

```
var dummy = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000000000000);
window.parent.location.href = window.parent.location.href.replace(/dummy=[0-9]+/, "dummy=" + dummy);
```

Comment: This worked very well, thanks!  I'm amazed not to find this problem documented elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks so much for this, I had the same issue as OP and it worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Phari's answer worked for me, with a few adjustments to fit my use case:

```
var rdm = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000000000000);
var url = window.parent.location.href;

if (url.indexOf("rdm") > 0) {
    window.parent.location.href = url.replace(/rdm=[0-9]+/, "rdm=" + rdm);

} else {
    var hsh = "";
    if (url.indexOf("#") > 0) {
        hash = "#" + url.split('#')[1];
        url = url.split('#')[0];
    }
    if (url.indexOf("?") > 0) {
        url = url + "&rdm=" + rdm + hsh;
    } else {
        url = url + "?rdm=" + rdm + hsh;
    }
    window.parent.location.href = url;

}
```

I'm sure this could be more efficient, but works ok.